# How can I access inner JSON elements with simple json in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I have this JSON for example:

```
{
"mesaje": [{
    "cif": "111",
    "data_creare": "29.11.2019 07:52:24",
    "id_solicitare": "222",
    "tip": "SOLICITARE",
    "id": "333",
    "detalii": "duplicat  pentru CUI 111"
}, {
    "cif": "444",
    "data_creare": "29.11.2019 07:59:37",
    "id_solicitare": "555",
    "tip": "SOLICITARE",
    "id": "666",
    "detalii": "duplicat pentru CUI 888"
}],
  "serial": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "cnp": "1888888888888888"
```

This is the code that I have written in Java:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {


        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("D:\\test.json")) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
            System.out.println(jsonObject);

            String cif = (String) jsonObject.get("serial");
            System.out.println(cif);
        }

    }
```

This prints out the serial number...but what I would like to do is to acces for example in mesaje -> cif , or. mesaje -> data_creare....the library used is json-simple...can you please help me with how I could do that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: JSON in your question i snot a valid json Please update with a valid json.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the documentation of json-simple and check various methods/examples to read/travserse the json at [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/).

Example to read mesaje -> cif.

```java
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
JSONArray mesaje = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("mesaje");
Iterator<String> iterator = mesaje.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject mesajeItem = iterator.next();
    System.out.println((String) mesajeItem.get("cif"));
}
```

More examples available at [json-simple examples](https://mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this below code.

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("mesaje");
  for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject obj= jsonArray.get(i);
  String cifId=obj.get("cif");
  String data_creare=obj.get("data_creare");
  String str1=obj.get("id_solicitare");
  String str2=obj.get("tip");
  String str3=obj.get("id");
  String str4=obj.get("detalii");
  String description=obj.get("description");
  System.out.println("Print here);        
}
 System.out.println("Print result here");
```